# Adding GIF Background to viewController with Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

I wanted to add GIF Background to my landing screen with swift, so I found this code online but when I try to use it on XCODE 7 with Swift 2.0

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    var filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("videoName", ofType: "gif")
    var gif = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath!)

    var webViewBG = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
    webViewBG.loadData(gif, MIMEType: "image/gif", textEncodingName: nil, baseURL: nil)
    webViewBG.userInteractionEnabled = false;
    self.view.addSubview(webViewBG)

    var filter = UIView()
    filter.frame = self.view.frame
    filter.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    filter.alpha = 0.05
    self.view.addSubview(filter)

    var welcomeLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.bounds.size.width, 100))
    welcomeLabel.text = "WELCOME"
    welcomeLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    welcomeLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(50)
    welcomeLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    self.view.addSubview(welcomeLabel)

    var loginBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(40, 360, 240, 40))
    loginBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    loginBtn.layer.borderWidth = 2
    loginBtn.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(24)
    loginBtn.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    loginBtn.setTitle("Login", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.view.addSubview(loginBtn)

    var signUpBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(40, 420, 240, 40))
    signUpBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    signUpBtn.layer.borderWidth = 2
    signUpBtn.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(24)
    signUpBtn.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    signUpBtn.setTitle("Sign Up", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.view.addSubview(signUpBtn)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
}


}
```

I get the following error :

[image: I have tried the suggested Edit from XCODE which is add "!" after the "gif" but this didn't work also]

Comment: tried that already , didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("videoName", ofType: "gif")
    let gif = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath!)

    let webViewBG = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
    webViewBG.loadData(gif!, MIMEType: "image/gif", textEncodingName: "utf-8", baseURL: NSURL())

    webViewBG.userInteractionEnabled = false;
    self.view.addSubview(webViewBG)

    let filter = UIView()
    filter.frame = self.view.frame
    filter.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    filter.alpha = 0.05
    self.view.addSubview(filter)

    let welcomeLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.bounds.size.width, 100))
    welcomeLabel.text = "WELCOME"
    welcomeLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    welcomeLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(50)
    welcomeLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    self.view.addSubview(welcomeLabel)

    let loginBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(40, 360, 240, 40))
    loginBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    loginBtn.layer.borderWidth = 2
    loginBtn.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(24)
    loginBtn.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    loginBtn.setTitle("Login", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.view.addSubview(loginBtn)

    let signUpBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(40, 420, 240, 40))
    signUpBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    signUpBtn.layer.borderWidth = 2
    signUpBtn.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(24)
    signUpBtn.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    signUpBtn.setTitle("Sign Up", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.view.addSubview(signUpBtn)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
}


}
```

Comment: @bpolat That is nice is there a way to make this work in the splash screen?

Comment: This is great. Any way to make it repeat/tile across the display?